# Insert into h2 table if not exists

Tags: sql, h2, insert-update

I am using H2. I want to insert a value into a table if it does not exist. I create the table with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $types 
  (type VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

And I want to do something like

```
REPLACE INTO types (type) values ('type1');
```

I found [an example](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html) about Replace that apparently works for MySQL but I am using h2.  But I get an error when I run this from my h2 console:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "REPLACE[*] INTO TYPES (TYPE) VALUES ('expense') "; expected "ROLLBACK, REVOKE, RUNSCRIPT, RELEASE, {"; SQL statement:
REPLACE INTO types (type) values ('expense') [42001-170] 42001/42001
```

I also tried

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO types (type) values ('expense');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO types (type) values ('expense') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type=type;
```

I don't care if the new insert overwrites the old data or if it just does not perform the new insert. Is there a way to do this with h2 database?

Comment: could you do a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#drop_table then start from scratch?

Comment: Thank you for the link to the grammar, it looks like there are no modifiers like the ones for MySQL on the Insert statement: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert. I don't think I will drop my table, though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [merge statement](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge) should allow you to achieve what you want. I'm no expert on H2, but I've used the `MERGE` statement in SQL Server several times and from the looks of that website it should do the trick.

From the website:

> Updates existing rows, and insert rows that don't exist. If no key column is specified, the primary key columns are used to find the row.